# Multiple JWT authorities/issuers in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4, bearer-token, ocelot

I'm trying to get JWT bearer authentication in an ASP.Net API gateway using Ocelot to work with multiple authorities/issuers. One issuer is Auth0 and the other is an in-house authentication server based on IdentityServer4; we are trying to migrate away from Auth0 but have external clients that still depend on it, so we would like to support both until everything is fully tested for them to switch.

According to [this MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/06/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/), it should be possible to use multiple authorities by setting `TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers` instead of `JwtBearerOptions.Authority`. However, I have tested this with and without Ocelot and no authentication occurs if the Authority is not set to the authority who issued the token, no matter the contents of `TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers`.

Does anybody know how to get this working? This is how I'm setting up authentication. It works only if the commented line is uncommented (and only for tokens issued by that single authority). I'm expecting Ocelot or ASP.Net Core to get the key from the issuing server; both provide JWKs by .well-known/openid-configuration which works with the ASP.Net Core middleware.

```cs
public static void AddJwtBearerAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services
        .AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            //options.Authority = configuration["Jwt:Authority"];
            options.Audience  = configuration["Jwt:Audience"];
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer           = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateAudience         = true,
                ValidAudience            = configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                ValidIssuers             = configuration
                    .GetSection("Jwt:Authorities")
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(kv => kv.Value)
                    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                    .ToArray()
            };
        });
}
```

The output of Ocelot when a client who has the wrong issuer (or when we're using `TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer`/`ValidIssuers`) connects is:

```
[16:35:37 WRN] requestId: _____, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Error Code: UnauthenticatedError Message: Request for authenticated route _____ by  was unauthenticated errors found in ResponderMiddleware. Setting error response for request path:_____, request method: POST
```

This is a client_credentials authentication hence the lack of a username after "by". As you can see Ocelot doesn't say what the exact problem is. The ASP.Net Core JWT bearer middleware (without Ocelot) just says the signature is invalid. I suspect it either isn't looking at the `TokenValidationParameters`, or I've misunderstood the purpose of them.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I figured out how to do it:

1. Create an authentication builder with `services.AddAuthentication()`. You can set the default scheme (to "Bearer") if you want but it's not necessary.
2. Add as many different JWT Bearer configurations as you want with `authenticationBuilder.AddJwtBearer()`, each with its own key (e.g "Auth0", "IS4", ...). I used a loop over an array in appsettings.json
3. Create a policy scheme with `authenticationBuilder.AddPolicyScheme` and give it the scheme name "Bearer" (use `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` to avoid having magic strings in your code) and set `options.ForwardDefaultSelector` in the callback to a function which returns one of the other scheme names ("Auth0", "IS4" or whatever you put) depending on some criterion. In my case it just looks for the scheme name in JWT issuer (if issuer contains "auth0" then the Auth0 scheme is used).

Code:

```cs
public static void AddMultiSchemeJwtBearerAuthentication(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    IConfiguration configuration
)
{
    // Create JWT Bearer schemes.
    var schemes = configuration
        .GetSection("Jwt")
        .GetChildren()
        .Select(s => s.Key)
        .ToList()
    ;
    var authenticationBuilder = services.AddAuthentication();
    foreach (var scheme in schemes)
    {
        authenticationBuilder.AddJwtBearer(scheme, options =>
        {
            options.Audience  = configuration[$"Jwt:{scheme}:Audience"];
            options.Authority = configuration[$"Jwt:{scheme}:Authority"];
        });
    }

    // Add scheme selector.
    authenticationBuilder.AddPolicyScheme(
        JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        "Selector",
        options =>
        {
            options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
            {
                // Find the first authentication header with a JWT Bearer token whose issuer
                // contains one of the scheme names and return the found scheme name.
                var authHeaderNames = new[] {
                    HeaderNames.Authorization,
                    HeaderNames.WWWAuthenticate
                };
                StringValues headers;
                foreach (var headerName in authHeaderNames)
                {
                    if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(headerName, out headers) && !StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(headers))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(headers))
                {
                    // Handle error. You can set context.Response.StatusCode and write a
                    // response body. Returning null invokes default scheme which will raise
                    // an exception; not sure how to fix this so the request is rejected.
                    return null;
                }

                foreach (var header in headers)
                {
                    var encodedToken = header.Substring(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme.Length + 1);
                    var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                    var decodedToken = jwtHandler.ReadJwtToken(encodedToken);
                    var issuer = decodedToken?.Issuer?.ToLower();
                    foreach (var scheme in schemes)
                    {
                        if (issuer?.Contains(scheme.ToLower()) == true)
                        {
                            // Found the scheme.
                            return scheme;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Handle error.
                return null;
            };
        }
    );
}
```

Nothing special is needed to get Ocelot to support this, just use "Bearer" as the authentication provider key and the scheme selector policy will be automatically invoked.

Comment: Why are you checking the "WWWAuthenticate" header as well? Isn't this a response header, and not usually included in a request?

Comment: A fantastic answer. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer! Instead of returning "null" when there are no headers, I just returned one of the authentication schemes and let it try (and fail) to authenticate. This results in a non-authenticated user.

Comment: Also, microsoft has some more docs on this scenario here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 15):

This is working example:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddAuthentication(options => 
   {
       options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   })
    //set default authentication 
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        //set the next authentication configuration to be used
        options.ForwardDefaultSelector = ctx => "idp4";

        //...rest of the options goes here
        };
    })
    .AddJwtBearer("idp4", options => 
     {
        //set the next authentication configuration to be used
        options.ForwardDefaultSelector = ctx => "okta";
        //options goes here
     })
    .AddJwtBearer("okta", options => 
     {
        //options goes here
     });
```

Comment: Thanks!! This was a lot easier than the other answers. It only took me about 5 minutes to get this solution implemented.

Answer (score 7):

A working solution for .net 5.

- This will work for multiple JWT bearer token issuers
- Default schema will do the routing to the corresponding schema

  ```
  // Get list of domains and audience from the config
       var authorities = Configuration["Auth:Domain"].Split(',').Distinct().ToList();
       var audience = Configuration["Auth:Audience"];
       // Add default empty schema schema selection policy
       var authenticationBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(
           options =>
           {
               // forward to corresponding schema based on token's issuer 
               // this will read the token and check the token issues , if the token issuer is registered in config then redirect to that schema
               options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
               {
                   string authorization = context.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];

                   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization))
                   {
                       if (authorization.StartsWith("Bearer ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                       {
                           var token = authorization.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();

                           var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                           if (jwtHandler.CanReadToken(token))
                           {
                               var jwtToken = jwtHandler.ReadJwtToken(token);
                               if (authorities.Contains(jwtToken.Issuer))
                                   return jwtToken.Issuer;
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   return null;
               };
           });

       // Register all configured schemas 
       foreach (var auth in authorities)
       {
           authenticationBuilder.AddJwtBearer(auth, options =>
           {

               options.SaveToken = true;
               options.Audience = audience;
               options.Authority = auth;
               options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
               {
                   NameClaimType = "sub",
                   ValidateIssuer = true,
                   ValidateAudience = true,
                   ValidateLifetime = true,
                   RequireSignedTokens = true,
                   ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
               };
           });

       }
  ```

Comment: This! Helped me when I had issues with one of the JwtBearer's config being wrong - it prevented the flow to continue to others, failing to process the JWT token. Lets say I had A, B and C configured. A was wrong. Token for C first went to A, failed, never tried B, never tried C so it threw Http500 and that was it. With this default selector I was able to target a specific config and get around the errors. Thanks!

Comment: This did it for me. Seriously, thanks so much for posting this!

Comment: This is exactly what helped me in my situation. Really appreciate! Massive thanks, bro! Be safe!

Comment: This is by far the best answer here