How to handle Dynamic Authority in ADB2C Multi-tenant in .NET 8.0 Web API Where each client site on different tenant
I am working on an ASP.NET 8.0 Web API and reacts app projects. These projects are registered in azure Active Directory B2C (ADB2C) under different tenants. Please refer #region Authentication & Security under full code snapshot
Tenant A: Web API project -> .NET 8.0 Web API
Tenant B: React Client App (consume APIs from Tenant A)
Tenant C: React Client App (consume APIs from Tenant A)
Tenant N: React Client App (consume APIs from Tenant A)
I need to make an API call from the React App to the .NET Web API, which is working fine. I have configure multiple clients in appsetting and seems all good,
however I am getting issue setting up Authority dynamically based on user from specific tenant. To test i put hardcore authority soon after
  builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
 .AddJwtBearer(options =>

and it works
but it won't work if I place it after  options.TokenValidationParameters to configure based on client,
     options.Authority = $"{client.Instance}/{client.TenantName}/{client.Policy}/v2.0/";
     options.MetadataAddress = $"{options.Authority}.well-known/openid-configuration";

i believe is too late by then, I need to dynamically configure Authority based on client login
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Claims;
using TXN.GV.Application.BackOffice;
using TXN.GV.Domain.Entity;
using TXN.GV.Enterprise.Data.DataContexts;

namespace MyApp.Web.APIs.Configuration
{
  public static class ServicesConfigurator
  {
    public static void Configure(WebApplicationBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        builder.Services.AddControllers();

        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

        #region Swagger
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v1" 
     });

            options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description = "JWT Authorization Bearer {token}",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme = "Bearer"
            });

            options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "Bearer"
                        },
                        Scheme = "oauth2",
                        Name = "Bearer",
                        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    },
                    new List<string>()
                }
            });
        });
        #endregion

        #region Data - DbContext
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnectionString"));
        });
        #endregion

        #region MediataR Container 
        //Global Visa Application BackOffice
        var assemblyBackOfficeName = "TXN.GV.Application.BackOffice";
        var assemblyBackOffice = Assembly.Load(assemblyBackOfficeName);
        builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(assemblyBackOffice));
        
        #endregion

        #region AutoMapper Configuration
        builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(ApplicationAssembly));
        #endregion

        #region CORS
        builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            });
        });

        #endregion

        #region Authentication & Security


        var azureAdB2CConfig = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C");
        var clientID = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C").GetSection("ClientId").Value;
        var signUpInPolicy = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C").GetSection("SignUpSignInPolicy").Value;
        var tenantName = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C").GetSection("TenantName").Value;
        var clientsConfig = configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C:Clients").Get<List<ClientConfig>>();

        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                var tenantBInstance = "https://appOnline.b2clogin.com";
                var tenantBName = "appOnline.onmicrosoft.com";
                options.Authority = $"{tenantBInstance}/{tenantBName}/{signUpInPolicy}/v2.0/";
                options.MetadataAddress = $"{options.Authority}.well-known/openid-configuration";
                // Explicitly set the valid issuer
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {

                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = azureAdB2CConfig["ClientId"],
                    ValidateLifetime = true,       
                    IssuerValidator = (issuer, securityToken, validationParameters) =>
                    {
                        var client = clientsConfig.FirstOrDefault(client =>
                            issuer.Equals($"{client.Instance}/{client.TenantId}/v2.0/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                        if (client != null)
                        {
      //NEED HELP HERE
                            //options.Authority = $"{client.Instance}/{client.TenantName}/{client.Policy}/v2.0/";
                            //options.Authority = $"{tenantBInstance}/{tenantBName}/{signUpInPolicy}/v2.0/";
                            //options.MetadataAddress = $"{options.Authority}.well-known/openid-configuration";

                            Console.WriteLine($"Valid issuer found: {issuer}");
                            Console.WriteLine($"Dynamic Authority set: {options.Authority}");
                            return issuer;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Invalid issuer. Received: {issuer}");
                            foreach (var conf in clientsConfig)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Expected Issuer for debug: {conf.Instance}/{conf.TenantId}/v2.0/");
                            }
                            throw new SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException($"Invalid issuer: {issuer}");
                        }
                    }

                };
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed,
                    OnMessageReceived = OnMessageReceived,
                    OnTokenValidated = OnTokenValidated
                };
            });

    }

    private static Task AuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Authentication failed: {context.Exception.Message}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static Task OnMessageReceived(MessageReceivedContext context)
    {
        var accessToken = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();
        context.Token = accessToken;
        Console.WriteLine($"Token received: {context.Token}");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }


    private static Task OnTokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context)
    {
        var token = context.SecurityToken;
        var claims = context.Principal.Claims;

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"User ID: {context.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)}");

            if (context.Request.Path.HasValue)
            {
                var userClaims = new UserClaims();

                var claimsIdentity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

                if (claimsIdentity == null || !claimsIdentity.Claims.Any()) { throw new ApplicationException("Identity shouldn't be null and must have claims."); }

                else
                { userClaims = ExtractUserClaims(claimsIdentity); }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static UserClaims ExtractUserClaims(ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        var userClaims = new UserClaims
        {
            UserId = Guid.TryParse(identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value, out Guid userId) ? userId : Guid.Empty,
            Iss = identity.FindFirst("iss")?.Value,
            FirstName = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value,
            LastName = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname)?.Value,
            DisplayName = identity.FindFirst("name")?.Value,
            Email = identity.FindFirst("emails")?.Value,
            IsUserAuthenticated = identity.IsAuthenticated,
            IsUserNew = identity.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == "newUser" && claim.Value == "true"),
            IssuedAt = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(long.Parse(identity.FindFirst("iat")?.Value ?? "0")).UtcDateTime,
            Expiration = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(long.Parse(identity.FindFirst("exp")?.Value ?? "0")).UtcDateTime,
            NotBefore = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(long.Parse(identity.FindFirst("nbf")?.Value ?? "0")).UtcDateTime
        };

        return userClaims;
    }

    #endregion



}

  public class ClientConfig
  {
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string TenantName { get; set; }
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
    public string Policy { get; set; }
    public string Instance { get; set; }
  }
}

appsetting.json
"AzureAdB2C": {
"Instance": "https://Machine.b2clogin.com",
"TenantName": "Machine",
"Tenant": "Machine.b2clogin.com",
"Domain": "Machine.onmicrosoft.com",
"ClientId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000008",
"TenantId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000019",
"SignUpSignInPolicy": "B2C_1_SignUpIn",
"ClientSecret": "xxx",
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
"Scope": "Core.API.All",
"Clients": [
  {
    "ClientId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000007",
    "TenantName": "FranceVisaOnline",
    "TenantId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000006",
    "Policy": "B2C_1_SignUpIn",
    "Instance": "https://FranceVisaOnline.b2clogin.com"
  },
  {
    "ClientId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003",
    "TenantName": "VisaOnline",
    "TenantId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000004",
    "Policy": "B2C_1_SignUpIn",
    "Instance": "https://VisaOnline.b2clogin.com"
  },
  {
    "ClientId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",
    "TenantName": "ItalyVisaOnline",
    "TenantId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
    "Policy": "B2C_1_SignUpIn",
    "Instance": "https://ItalyVisaOnline.b2clogin.com"
   }
  ]
 },


The authority must be set as https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations  for  ADB2C Multi-tenant

i did
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations";
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters..........
and get error IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.

is it applicable for ADB2C?

i am reading When using Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C) and attempting to set up a multi-tenant configuration, the suggestion to use https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations as the authority is not appropriate. This URL is typically used for Azure AD (not B2C) scenarios and targets Azure AD tenants in general, not specific Azure AD B2C tenants. For Azure AD B2C, each tenant has its unique authority URL based on the tenant's domain name and the specific user flow (or policy) you are using.

Is this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276977/azure-ad-b2c-error-idx10501-signature-validation-failed

is getting complex .. struggling

I can setup correct authority for one tenant along with policy options.Authority = $"{tenantBInstance}/{tenantBName}/{signUpInPolicy}/v2.0/";  and it works my issue is dynamic authority for ADB2C in multi tenants solution

Would this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952600/multiple-jwt-authorities-issuers-in-asp-net-core

I have found the answer from following video
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2rhhlwKO_Xw&t=38s


Create multiple schema for each ADB2C registered App Tenants.
AddPolicyScheme within Security Authentication which can point to right tenant config based on received token
Register each tenant under AddJwtBearer("unique schema Name", options =>

